# Resize by default TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE for the first time, and I love it, but is a bit closed.
I'd like to get images resized by default, this is, when adding an image, put it by default on 300px width, for example (then the user can make it bigger or smaller dragging).

I don't know where to touch! Is there a command within the lists of images (the js you can attach to make TinyMCE show a list of images)? Or I have to hack css? Or I have to dive into TinyMCE code?

Thank you in advance
Marc

Comment: Hi man, which version of TinyMCE you were using. The one I have doesn not contains the code `insertAndClose : function()`

Comment: @Kami I don't remember the version. But this question is from back 2013, so the code might have changed a lot. And I won't recommend anybody to use a 2013 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with changing code files then proceed as follows

Open tiny_mce/plugins/advimage/js/image.js

```
Locate insertAndClose : function()
```

Insert after 
     var ed = tinyMCEPopup.editor, ......;

```
 if(f.width.value == ""){
 f.width.value = 300;
 }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That was the place!! I changed a bit your code (height wasn't rescaled), and it works perfectly now!!
if(f.width.value == "" || f.width.value > 300){
if.height.value = (300*f.height.value)/f.width.value;
f.width.value = 300;
}

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There are several options. I would go the css way. Check out the tinycme init configuration setting [content_css](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acontent_css). Using an additioanl own css file enables you to setthe width of images to 300px easily.

Comment: If I put: .mceContentBody img{ max-width: 300px !important; }, then I can't make photos bigger (smaller yes), and photos are only changed width (not rescaled). If I only put .mceContentBody img{ width: 300px !important; }, as you can imagine, I can't change its width. Any little css hack to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: min-width doesn't resize image, it only limits the resize. This means, If I put a 1000px width image, with "width" I can't change its widht; with a "max-width", I can make it smaller (not bigger) and width "min-width", it is at first 1000px and then I can make it smaller till "min-width". As well as this, it doesn't scale image, the height is the original (and the image is horrible, then).

Comment: what about removing the width when the user tries to change the size?

Comment: you mean using javascript and playing around with tags? I don't think it has to be too much complicated, I'll wait for another response. Thanks anyway